# ansible playbook is connecting with admin user by default

Tags: ansible

when i run ansible playbook, by defult it's trying to connect remote servers with admin user, not considering user in play book

```
root@c63fe05c2307:/# ansible-playbook play.yml

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [shell] *******************************************************************
fatal: [172.17.0.3]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: admin@172.17.0.3: Permission denied (publickey,password).\r\n", "unreachable": true}
        to retry, use: --limit @/play.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
172.17.0.3                 : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

actually i mention remote user as sdnask user  below is my playbook

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  remote_user: sdnask
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo

  tasks:
  - shell: mkdir /test2
```

whatever user i mentioned in playbook no matter, but it's trying to connect through admin user , even if i am trying to run `ansible all -u sdnask -m ping` it's trying to connect with admin user. can anyone please suggest what causing issue?

Comment: `remote_user` is not the only place you can set it. [Another important thing to consider (for all versions) is that connection variables override config, command line and play/role/task specific options and keywords.](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable)

Comment: what are connection variables? where can i find those,

Comment: There's an example of one, most likely the culprit, in the document I linked above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try *ansible_user* to ssh connect.

```
ansible_user: sdnask
```

You might want to run the playbook below to find where does the *admin* come from.

```
- hosts: 172.17.0.3
  tasks:
    - name: List all vars
      vars: 
        msg: |
        Module Variables ("vars"):
        --------------------------------
        {{ vars | to_nice_json }}

        Environment Variables ("environment"):
        --------------------------------
        {{ environment | to_nice_json }}

        GROUP NAMES Variables ("group_names"):
        --------------------------------
        {{ group_names | to_nice_json }}

        GROUPS Variables ("groups"):
        --------------------------------
        {{ groups | to_nice_json }}

        HOST Variables ("hostvars"):
        --------------------------------
        {{ hostvars | to_nice_json }} 

      debug:
        msg: "{{ msg.split('\n') }}"
```